# Knockout foreach binding inside a binding (array within an array)

Tags: arrays, data-binding, foreach, knockout.js

i have two classes; users and readings. this relates to healthcare to each user has an array of readings:

```
/*
 * Reading class
 * containts health readings
 */
function Reading(date,weight,glucose)
{
    var self = this;

    self.date=ko.observable(date);
    self.weight=ko.observable(weight);
    self.glucose=ko.observable(glucose);

      self.formattedWeight = ko.computed(function(){
        var formatted = self.weight();

        return formatted+" lb"
    });
}

/*
 * User class
 * contains a user name, date, and an array or readings
 */
function User(name,date,readings) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = name;
    self.date = date;
    self.readingsArray = ko.observableArray([
        new Reading(99,99)
    ]); 
}
```

i know how to use a foreach binding to display the information for a reading or a user. but im not sure how to show the readings inside of a user?

is there a way to use a nested foreach binding or a with binding? here is my html:

```
<h2>Users (<span data-bind="text: users().length"></span>)</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>User name</th><th>Date</th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
     <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: date" /></td>
        <td data-bind="text: readingsArray"></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeUser">Remove</a></td>               
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addUser">Add User</button>

<h2>Readings (<span data-bind="text: readings().length"></span>)</h2>
    <table>
    <thead><tr>
       <th>Date</th><th>Weight</th><th>Glucose</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: readings">
     <tr>
        <td strong data-bind="text: date"></td>
        <td strong data-bind="text: formattedWeight"></td>
        <td strong data-bind="text: glucose"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my model if anyone is interested. any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function userHealthModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.inputWeight = ko.observable();
    self.inputDate = ko.observable();
    self.inputId = ko.observable();
    self.inputGlucose = ko.observable();

    // Operations
    self.addUser = function(){
        self.users.push(new User("",0,0,(new Reading(0,0))));
    }
    //adds a readings to the edittable array of readings (not yet the reading array in a user)
    self.addReading = function(){
        var date = self.inputDate();
        var weight = self.inputWeight();
        var glucose = self.inputGlucose();
        if((weight&&date)||(glucose&&date))
        {
            self.readings.push(new Reading(date,weight,glucose));
        }
        else{
            alert("Please complete the form!")
        }
    }

    self.removeUser = function(userName){self.users.remove(userName)}

    //editable data
     self.readings = ko.observableArray([
        new Reading(12,99,3),new Reading(22,33,2),
        new Reading(44,55,3)
    ]);

      self.users = ko.observableArray([
        new User("George",2012),
        new User("Bindu",2012)
    ]);

}

ko.applyBindings(new userHealthModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want the Readings rendered, but here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/aZnzg/

You can simply use another foreach to start a new binding context, and then render the properties as you wish.

Comment: sorry i should have been more specific. i meant the reading array inside the user class

Comment: Yes, that is what my example renders.  It displays the Readings that are associated with the User.  Notice in my fiddle that it displays '99 | 99' as that is what you have assigned to the Reading.

Comment: wow thanks i must have over looked that! Thank you very much!